# How do you pass a derived class if you only know the base class?

Tags: c++, class, object

I apologize in advance as I am a beginner in OO-programming.

I have a base class called Hero, with three derived classes Archer, Warrior, and Mage. The user is prompted to select one of them, and an object of the appropriate derived class is created. They have different initial values and member functions, and the next step is to pass this object to another function.

Let's say the function is called battle(), and it takes the object as an argument. How do I go about doing this? Do I have to create three separate battle() or is there a way to pass the object without the need to specify the derived class?

```
void Hero::init(string job)
{  
    if (job == "archer")
        Archer archer;
    else if (job == "mage")
        Mage mage;
    else
        Warrior warrior;

    battle(); // What to put as argument?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`battle()` should take a reference or (smart) pointer to the base class as an argument. For example:

```c++
void battle(std::shared_ptr<Hero> ptr);
```

And your argument should be a smart pointer as well:

```c++
void Hero::init(const std::string& job)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Hero> ptr;

    if (job == "archer")
        ptr = std::make_shared<Archer>();
    else if (job == "mage")
        ptr = std::make_shared<Mage>();
    else
        ptr = std::make_shared<Warrior>();

    battle(ptr);
}
```

`std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer class that encapsulates dynamic memory allocation and resource acquisition for a pointer. This is so that we don't have to write `new` every where. Moreover, when the smart pointer is destroyed (meaning no more copies of `ptr` exist, if any) then `delete` is called on the contained `Hero` pointer.

The above works because all three classes are derived from `Hero` so the addresses of those derived class pointers can be pointed to by the base class.

Comment: std::shared_ptr and std::make_shared don't seem to compile. I'm using the latest version of Code Blocks.

Comment: @geft You need to `#include` the `<memory>` file.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to create 3 different `battle` functions, avoiding this is precisely the purpose of inheritance.

You can create a single `battle` function:

```
void battle(Hero& hero)
{
}
```

You can call it as follows:

```
battle(archer);
battle(mage);
battle(warrior);
```

but you will need to create your heros in another way, because as they are created now, they fall out of scope as soon as the `if` or `else` are done.

Comment: Thank you, but what does `Hero&` mean? I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: That is a reference. It means you work with the object created outside the battle function

Answer (score 2):

This is where you should use run-time polymorphism.
Instead of creating local derived class object instances, create a base class pointer and point it to the derived class instance:

```
Hero* hero = new Archer();
Hero* hero = new Mage();
Hero* hero = new Warrior();
```

Then you could pass base class pointer `Hero*` to your method `battle`

```
battle(hero)
```

The signature of your method would be:

```
void battle(Hero* )
```

This means, battle method can accept any kind of Hero at run-time, be it an archer, mage or a warrior.

Comment: This still creates derived class object instances.

Comment: Rephrased the sentence.

Comment: @cppcoder I'm a little confused. You declare a pointer than points to a dynamically allocated object. How does this work when the pointer and the object are of different classes?

Comment: This is the basis of run-time polymorphism. In your case, `Archer` is a `Hero`, `Mage` is a `Hero` and `Warrior` is a `Hero`. By inheritance you establish an `is-a` relationship between classes.